# Android ANR on registerReceiver

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, localbroadcastmanager

My app crashes sometimes on this line:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).
            registerReceiver(handler, new IntentFilter("DATA_UPDATE"));
```

In traces.txt I found out, that registerReiceiver is blocked by a thread, where a broadcast is send.

```
schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=141 stm=2 core=0
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(LocalBroadcastManager.java:~240)
```

How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: Probably context is null and no need to pass Application Context, just use current component Context

Comment: I bet that the problem is that you are doing something stupid (like inf. loop or some hard work) in onReceive of your receiver implementation

Comment: @Selvin so when a thread handles a onReceive, no new receiver can be registered?

Comment: I don't know ... it was the blind guess/ the place where i would start to search ... second is: too much registerd receivers

Comment: Check the cases where handler can be NULL.